# How to add new collection to existing document React v18, Firebasev9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Creating user:

```
  const register=async()=>{
    try{
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, registerEmail, registerPassword)
    const newUser = await addDoc(collection(db, "Users"), {
        email:registerEmail
      });
    setEmail(newUser.email) 
    navigate("/home");
    }catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

I tried to store email to match it with firestore user data email

Below is other component where I try to add new collection to specific user, but fail to do so

```
const createAnime = async () => {

const addAnime= await addDoc(collection(db,"Users",user.id,"anime"),{
        title,genre,numb,comment,rating,aid
      })
  }
```

I've tried various solutions. The goal is to add (title, genre, number, etc.) as separate documents to the user created. I fail to match the data from auth user to the same user data created in Direstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `addDoc()` when adding user's document to Firestore that generates a random document ID but then trying to add a sub-collection to document with user's UID (which probably doesn't even exist). Instead set the document ID to user's UID at first place as shown below:

```
const register = async () => {
  try {
    const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, registerEmail, registerPassword)
    
    const newUser = await setDoc(doc(db, "Users", user.uid), {
      email: registerEmail
    });
    
    setEmail(registerEmail)
    navigate("/home");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, will try to look at it, I am kinda new to coding as well, so confusion is not avoidable

Comment: With this code example I receive the following error: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Users/(document id) has 2.

Comment: @Deividas correct. There should be `doc()` instead of `collection()`

Comment: Thank you, once again, it did work nicely. Now I need to add the data to those documents as I asked in the initial post. Any advice or idea how to add the user specific data? Appreciated